# How to configure to compile postgresql in codeblock?

Tags: postgresql

As I need to make some extensions of PostgreSQL. I would like to  compile the source code in codeblock. I have created a project file and added the source codes recursively. After rebuild, it reports such error. I think it should be the link address error, what address should I fill in link address and include address? thanks.

```
ubescan.l: In function 'cube_yylex':
cubescan.l:46:1: error: 'yylval' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:46:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
cubescan.l:46:30: error: 'CUBEFLOAT' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:47:22: error: 'O_BRACKET' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:48:22: error: 'C_BRACKET' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:49:22: error: 'O_PAREN' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:50:22: error: 'C_PAREN' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:51:22: error: 'COMMA' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l: In function 'cube_scanner_init':
cubescan.l:97:2: error: 'scanbuflen' undeclared (first use in this function)
cubescan.l:98:2: error: 'scanbuf' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Have you read the chapters in the PostgreSQL manual on [Installation from Source Code](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/installation.html) or [Installation from Source Code on Windows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/install-windows.html)? Also, are you sure your changes will require source compilation? Postgres provides a large variety of [mechanisms for extending functionality](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/server-programming.html) most of which do not require compiling the entire source.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do regarding extending functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to add `CUBE` (and maybe `ROLLUP`) syntax to PostgreSQL.  If this is the case, and if you are trying to make a contribution to PostgreSQL, this is probably the wrong place to ask.  A much better approach is to get on the PostgreSQL email lists, particularly pgsql-hackers, and discuss your design there.  If there are areas where the docs IMSOP pointed you to are incomplete, that would be the be the best place to ask.

The reason you should ask there instead of here is not just the sort of help you can expect with technical problems, but that the community appreciates some contact in discussing designs before they are implemented.  There is a strong culture of peer review in PostgreSQL, and CUBE/ROLLUP functionality is desired by the community or at least was on the TODO last time I checked.  Working with other developers is the best way to accomplish something like this.

(Pardon me if this answer sounds too much like "clippy")